# Copy files from local Sharepoint Document Library to Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, cloud, office365

We maintain a local SharePoint Intranet here at work. We have made the switch to Office 365 for our email services and are in the process of transitioning most of our local intranet Sharepoint site to the cloud service. Right now we use Costpoint to post employee pay stubs (pdf's) to a document library. The private document library permissions are set up as this:

Private Folder:Read permissions for all

> Employee Folder > Paystubs Folder: "That" Employee access and "Utility" account access only.

The Utility account is the account Costpoint uses to post the pdf files to the private document libraries. At this point, instead of going in and trying to modify Costpoint, we want to continue posting the pdf's to the local intranet library, and then copy them to the SharePoint Online site with the same file structure and permissions in place.

What would be the best way to go about this. Powershell script? Or is there a tool that we can use to accomplish this? Would the script have to be run manually or can we run it automatically when the folders are updated with new information?

Comment: you can try Drop-off library(create an event listener to copy file to drop-off lib). In central admin, you can configure the drop-off destination for online site. Or write a CSOM solution it could be service, timer job etc. But csom has limitation of 3mb file size, but there is workaround for this as well.